# Fused Location Crash

Tags: java, android

Hi i've been trying to get fused location to work but always get app crash can anyone tell me wgy? tank you

getting this error:

> 12-11 02:08:54.525: E/AndroidRuntime(5972): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.teste/com.example.teste.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected. Call connect() and wait for onConnected() to be called.

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.teste"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.teste.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Main:

```
package com.example.teste;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

LocationClient mLocationClient;
Location mCurrentLocation;
TextView v1,v2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int resultCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Toast.makeText(this, "Serciços Google Play disponiveis",     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
    mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
    mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    v1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    v2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    v1.setText(Double.toString(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()));
    v2.setText(Double.toString(mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()));
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
     mLocationClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
     mLocationClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


@Override
public void onDisconnected() {
     Toast.makeText(this, "Disconnected. Please re-connect.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

}
```

Layoout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't call `mLocationClient.getLastLocation()` until `onConnected()` is called. Move that call (and anything that depends on it) to your `onConnected()` method.

Comment: I guided by Google documentation but they only had partial code so ok that might be it, but i previusly moved the code to onConnected() and no value was return, (extracting the latitude and longitude)
Also guided by a lynda.com example that used the method outside the onConnect() on a specific method created by the user, did the api changed(lynda.com video was from march this year) or is there anything else that needs to be done to work that way?
Tank You

Comment: Never mind i totally forgot i had almost every app and service restricted to background access to GPRS and play services where also blocked.
Tank You

Comment: But still if there is any way of doing this outside the onConnected please tell me. Tank You once again

Comment: @user3089297 - as long as `onConnected` has been called, you can call `getLastLocation` from anywhere in your Activity. You may want to set a `boolean` variable to `true` in `onConnected` and `false` in `onDisconnected` - that way you can just check that variable before calling `getLastLocation`.

Comment: But i had it connected, connected onStart disconnected onStop, i even tryed to call mLocationClient.connect(); on the onCreate just before the remaining code but the error was the same as i posted, (i think need to try again to see if wasn't just the blocked service) tank you once again.